# Old values are not setting properly in the checkboxes on edit blade laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my laravel application I have a table to store job deatails.

following is my Job.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Job extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    // Define the table associated with the model
    protected $table = 'jobs';

    // The attributes that are mass assignable
    protected $fillable = [
        'company_id',
        'job_title',
        'employment_type',
        'primary_tag',
        'job_description',
        'how_to_apply',
        'seo_support',
        'premium_support',
        'show_logo',
        'highlight_post',
        'sticky_24_hours',
        'sticky_1_week',
        'sticky_1_month',
        'minimum_salary',
        'maximum_salary',
        'compensation_type',
        'benefits',
        'seo_title',
        'seo_meta_desc',
        'user_id',
        'invoice_email',
        'is_published',
        'is_active',
        'is_expired',
        'paid_amount',
        'is_paid',
        'views',
        'timeDifference',
    ];

    // Cast attributes to appropriate data types
    protected $casts = [
        'seo_support' => 'boolean',
        'premium_support' => 'boolean',
        'show_logo' => 'boolean',
        'highlight_post' => 'boolean',
        'sticky_24_hours' => 'boolean',
        'sticky_1_week' => 'boolean',
        'sticky_1_month' => 'boolean',
        'benefits' => 'array',
        'secondary_tag' => 'array',
        'is_published' => 'boolean',
        'is_active' => 'boolean',
        'is_expired' => 'boolean',
        'is_paid' => 'boolean',
    ];

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id');
    }

    public function employmentType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(EmploymentType::class, 'employment_type');
    }

    public function primaryTag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PrimaryTag::class, 'primary_tag');
    }

    public function secondaryTags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SecondaryTag::class, 'job_secondary_tag', 'job_id', 'secondary_tag_id');
    }
}
```

Following is my SecondaryTag.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SecondaryTag extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'secondary_tags';

    protected $fillable = [
        'tag_name',
    ];

    // Define any relationships or additional methods here
}
```

When I create a new job, my secondary tags are stored in an array format.

```
Example: ["1","3","4","13","16"]
```

Now I'm trying to work on the edit job. I tried this on my edit jobs blade

```
<!-- Secondary Tags (Checkboxes) -->
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label">Other Tags, Keywords, Stack</label>
                        <div class="row">
                            <!-- Loop through secondary tags and create checkboxes -->
                            @foreach ($secondaryTags as $secondaryTag)
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                                            id="secondary_tag_{{ $secondaryTag->id }}" name="secondary_tags[]"
                                            value="{{ $secondaryTag->id }}"
                                            {{ $job->secondaryTags->contains($secondaryTag->id) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="secondary_tag_{{ $secondaryTag->id }}">
                                            {{ $secondaryTag->tag_name }}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Even though this prints all the secondary tags, it's not checked the already checked check boxes.

In my previous example check boxes with ["1","3","4","13","16"] id's should have been checked.

But they remain unchecked.

Following is my controller function

```
public function edit(Job $job)
    {
        // Fetch the secondary tags and benefits to pass to the view
        $primaryTags = PrimaryTag::all();
        $employerTypes = EmploymentType::all();
        $secondaryTags = SecondaryTag::all();
        $benefits = Benefit::all();
    
        // Retrieve the company details for editing
        return view('profile/org/jobs/edit', compact('job', 'secondaryTags', 'benefits'));
    }
```

what am i doing wrong, How can I display the checked old values correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Why to make things complicated? You can take full advantage of blade template. Try like

`@checked($job->secondaryTags->contains($secondaryTag->id))`

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
       id="secondary_tag_{{ $secondaryTag->id }}"
       name="secondary_tags[]"
       value="{{ $secondaryTag->id }}"
       @checked($job->secondaryTags->contains($secondaryTag->id))>
```

Hope this helps.